# How can I get stripe working on prestashop?

Tags: stripe-payments, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have installed the stripe plugin on the latest build of prestashop 1.7.6.1. the plugin is up-to-date and seems installed fine. In the payment are I have ticked stripe to show on all pages and for all shipping methods.

When I go to check out I click pay by car and all I get is a blank red box.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any errors in your browser console? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears Stripe have changed there code and the way use the API. Before it used a form on your page but now they make you go off to there site and make payment. Th